# Selenium browser capability fontSize

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-options, desiredcapabilities

Is it possible to change the fontsize of the browser through capabilities? if so how?
manually we can set it from chrome>>Settings>> Appearance>> font Size..

so, wanted to set it at initial launch of browser and work.

Had tried to find it in chromeOptions but couldn't
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

any possibility?

Couldnt tag, webdriverJS.
i am using typescript for webdriverJS API

Comment: tag your binding language as well